# How to embed data uri in css files automatically in a directory with many subdirectories?

Tags: css, linux, bash, shell, data-uri

I am using [cssembed](http://github.com/nzakas/cssembed) to encodes all image references in the css files to base64 and replace the original css file with the changes. However, what I want to do is automate the process for all the css files in my folder with many subfolders/subdirectories. 
 I tried the following:

```
java -jar cssembed-0.4.5.jar *.css > *.css
```

But it produces the following output:

```
bash: *.css: ambiguous redirect
```

I also tried

```
java -jar cssembed-0.4.5.jar *.css
```

But this only outputs the result in the terminal , does not replace the file with the encoded bits.

How to solve this ? Any suggestions?

NOTE: I am trying to do this on Ubuntu terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` to locate all files in all subdirectories too:

```
find -name "*.css" -exec java -jar cssembed-0.4.5.jar '{}' > tmp \; -exec mv tmp '{}' \;
```

Here `tmp` is a temporary file that is written to, which is necessary because when you use `>` the file you are writing to is truncated immediately. The second `-exec` is only run if the first one returns successfully, overwriting the original file with the contents of `tmp`.

If the code above isn't working for you, perhaps you could try this:

```
find -name "*.css" -exec sh -c 'java -jar cssembed-0.4.5.jar "$0" > tmp && mv tmp "$0"' '{}' \;
```

This invokes a separate shell for each file that is found. `$0` is the name of the file that has been found.